# Fragment tabs in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I am new to objective C. As we have fragment tabs in Android, so that only a part of activity( background remaining same) changes, what is to be used to replicate the same in ios with tabs on top in a view controller ? Any suggestions would be great Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Tab Bar Controller as described here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

Note that the tabs (fragments) are at the bottom as opposed to android

Comment: can tab bar controllers be used to keep a constant background and change only a certain part of view controller when the tabs are switched?

Comment: I never done it but I believe you can use one view controller and change its view elements (hide/show/add/remove) when a tab is tapped. Read about the architecture and try something simple just to see how it works and try to customize it from there

Comment: So are you suggesting to drop the idea of tab view controller and do our own custom controller?

Comment: no, use a tab view controller but its internal view controller (the one created for each tab) should be one and this one view controller will be responsible for changing its view content.

Comment: ok. But will i be able to keep a constant back ground when the views for each tab is loaded?

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625849/one-viewcontroller-for-multiple-uitabbar-sections. and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682651/same-view-in-multiple-tabs. There are the cons of pros of doing that so make sure you read it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TabBarController. In tabbar controller, each tab is independent
I dont know a lot about Android code but if in Android, you have Activity -> ios have ViewController and each TabBar could control a ViewController. So you could do a part of activities changes.

In other hand, you could custom the tabbar Icon for your self!! Refer to:http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/

Comment: UISegmentedControl could be used in your case